# How to allow only selection of Sundays on my datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How do I allow only selection of Sundays on my datepicker? I did a little bit of research and came across a lot of answers stating that I need to use beforeShowDay, These are my codes:

```
   <div class="pickaDate" style="width:25%;">
<input type='text' id="date" />
          <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      return [date.getDay()===0];
    }
});
});

</script>
</div>
```

I got the codes from [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Fy9/) but changed the input type to date because that's the only way the datepicker would appear. But I can still select all the dates.

My knowledge on this is basic at best. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[`beforeShowDay`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay): *A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with `true/false` indicating whether or not this date is selectable*

Try this:

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [date.getDay() === 0];
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="date" type="text">
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/Fa8Xx/3865/)

Comment: Your code works on jfiddle but not on my project file.

Comment: what files are you referring to?

Comment: I have added all the required links into my html file but the dropdown still refuses to show as long as my input type is "text".

Comment: It actually works on its own but does not the moment i put it into my project file.